# How to run load test for the REST SERVICE in soapui

Tags: soapui

I have list of testcases in my testuites for my application. Out of which I need to run load test for the app.

Example of my first testcase is

```
Steps: 
1. Login as admin
1a. Extract session from response in step 1
2. Data source for list of users to be added
3. Add users (data will be taken from step 2)
4. Verify the response using groovy
5. Dataloop
6. Logout admin

Testcase 2:
1. Data source list of users added in testcase 1
2. Login new users
2a. Extract session
3. Change password
4. Login again with the updated password
5. Logout new user
6. Dataloop
```

How to do load testing. Will it run sequentially without changing any step and maintain correct session when on parallel load test??

Comment: May be you should try running the test and find out exact issue rather than having uncertain information.

Comment: In SOAPUI, you will use functional test cases to your load test. In functional testing you can set how the test case should be executed. Parallel or Sequential. You create load testing scenario from your functional test cases. You can check more details in the official documentation. https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/getting-started.html and https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html